# Java eclipse coding error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps

In my `activity_main.xml` I have included `android:id="@+id/retrieve_location_button"` 
and when I use

```
retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);
```

in `mainactivity.java`. I get an saying `retrieve_location_button` cannot be resolved or is not a field. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make variable for that

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button retrieveLocationButton;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

   }
}
```

Comment: where do I make in variable? in which file? activity_main,manifest or mainactivity.java. Sorry im pretty new to these things.

Comment: dud just do like this

     Button retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your R classes have not been built. Are there ANY errors in your code or your XML files? Try doing a Project > Clean. That may do it; or it will tell you if you have any errors.

Comment: Try doing a clean. If that doesn't work, close Eclipse and re-start. Sometimes that will do it if it can't find an id reference.